# How can I get a list of all touches that are currently on a Tap Gesture Recognizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need a way to get the positions of all touches on a Tap Gesture Recognizer. How do I do this?

Edit: The Tap Gesture Recognizer isn't necessary, I just need a way to get the location of all current touches on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `numberOfTouches` method of `UIGestureRecognizer` to get current touches, and then call `locationOfTouches` to return the location of each touch as a CGPoint:

```
    let touches = recognizer.numberOfTouches()

    for touch in 0..<touches {
        recognizer.locationOfTouch(touch, inView: view)
    }
```